# Add dynamic css class to every row/cell in CGridView

Tags: gridview, yii

I'm a student and working on my practical project. Its a web application which tracks google rankings for keywords and shows them as a table. Now I want to color every row green, if the current ranking is better than the previous, red if the ranking went down etc. How can I implement this in Yii with CGridView? Currently I have the following solution. In the ControllerClass I have a function

```
public function getCssClass($data)
{
    $cssClass;

    if('($data->current_pos>$data->prev_pos) || ($data->current_pos===null && $data->prev_pos!==null)')
    {
        $cssClass='rdown';
    }
    elseif('$data->current_pos<$data->prev_pos')
    {
        $cssClass='rup';
    }
    else
    {
        $cssClass='requal';
    }

    return $cssClass;
}
```

And in the view I call this function at 'rowCssClassExpression':

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'keyword-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$keywordDataProvider,
'rowCssClassExpression' => $this->getCssClass($data),
'columns'=>array(
    'keyword_name',
    array(
        'name'=>'current_pos',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align: center'),
    ),
    array(
        'name'=>'prev_pos',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align: center'),
    ),
    array(
        'name'=>'top_pos',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align: center'),
    ),
    'url',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{view}{delete}',
        'viewButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/keyword/view", array("id"=>$data->id))',
        'deleteButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("/keyword/delete", array("id"=>$data->id))',
    ),
),
'nullDisplay'=>'-',
)); ?>
```

This is my table:

Keyword current previous

Keyword1   7       7

Keyword2   8       10

Keyword3   26      20

But the html result is that every row gets the class 'rdown'. I can't find my mistake :-( If someone could help and point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'($data->current_pos>$data->prev_pos) || ($data->current_pos===null && $data->prev_pos!==null)'` in your method is a string and it is always `true`. That's why `rdown` is returned. Why do you use `'` to wrap the condition?

Please also note that [rowCssClassExpression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#rowCssClassExpression-detail) is a PHP expression so probably the result of your method should be wrapped in quotes:

```
'rowCssClassExpression' => '"' . $this->getCssClass($data) . '"',
```

Unfortunately this will not work too due to model's instance `$data` is defined within `rowCssClassExpression` (and evaluated for each row of the grid) but not in context of your view.

As a solution you can create `getCssClass` as a method of your model. Then your expression will look like this:

```
'rowCssClassExpression' => '$data->getCssClass()',
```

To specify a CSS class for each particular cell you can also look at [cssClassExpression](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridColumn#cssClassExpression-detail) of `CGridColumn` class.

Comment: Thx Ezze. Still not working. I wrapped the condition in quotes because I get no value if I do not use quotes. But still you're right. It doesn't make sense to have such a condition.

Comment: In my getCssClass() I tried: $current_pos=$data->current_pos; and returned gettype($current_pos). Result is null. $current_pos='$data->current_pos'; returns the correct values as class names in my html: 7, 8, 26. But the problem is that in the function itself before displaying in the browser $current_pos is a string containing '$data->current_pos'. So I can't use it in my if conditions. When I try to cast the var to int the result of the casting is always 0. Also if I use intval(). How do I get the value of '$data->current_pos' as an int value so I can use them in my conditions correctly?

Comment: I still believe that specifying `rowCssClassExpression` as `$this->getCssClass($data)` is wrong because `$data` is a model instance defined only within `rowCssClassExpression` that is a string property of `CGridView`. In your case you call `$this->getCssClass($data)` passing undefined `$data` and result of this call is considered as PHP expression to determine a CSS class (but not as CSS class itself).

Comment: So the proper way to set a row class could be: `'rowCssClassExpression' => '$this->getCssClass($data)'`. But in context of this expression `$this` is a `CGridView` instance but not the controller. That's why I recommend you to move `getCssClass` method to your model (`'rowCssClassExpression' => '$data->getCssClass()'`) and access this model's properties within the method using `$this->` reference as usual. `'$data->getCssClass()'` will be evaluated as PHP expression, method `getCssClass()` of the model will be called then and a string result of this call will become a CSS class of your row.